# Finding current active entry from a list of courses

Tags: r, dataframe, recursion, parent-child, igraph

I have a requirement to find the 'current' equivalent course from a list of courses. The list is in a fairly simple format, from an SQL query, and looks like below:

| Course_Code | Course_Title | Course_Status | Parent_Course |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HLT31802 | Title1a | Superseded | HLT31807 |
| HLT31807 | Title1b | Superseded | HLT31812 |
| HLT31812 | Title1c | Superseded | HLT35015 |
| HLT35015 | Title1d | Superseded | HLT35021 |
| HLT35021 | Title1e | Current | None |
| ABC12345 | Title2a | Superseded | ABC67890 |
| ABC67890 | Title2b | Current | None |

I'm sure the solution has something to do with recursion, but can't get my head around it. I am happy to post code Ive tried but I didnt get very far without creating multiple columns (child1, child2, etc) in SQL.

Required output would be something like this:

| Course_Code | Current_Course |
| --- | --- |
| HLT31802 | HLT35021 |
| HLT31807 | HLT35021 |
| HLT31812 | HLT35021 |
| HLT35015 | HLT35021 |
| HLT35021 | HLT35021 |
| ABC12345 | ABC67890 |
| ABC67890 | ABC67890 |

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another `igraph` option

```
df %>%
  mutate(Parent_Course = ifelse(Parent_Course == "None", Course_Code, Parent_Course)) %>%
  select(Course_Code, Parent_Course, everything()) %>%
  group_by(Grp = membership(components(graph_from_data_frame(.)))[Course_Code]) %>%
  mutate(Parent_Course = Parent_Course[Course_Status == "Current"]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

gives

```
  Course_Code Parent_Course Course_Title Course_Status   Grp
  <chr>       <chr>         <chr>        <chr>         <dbl>
1 HLT31802    HLT35021      Title1a      Superseded        1
2 HLT31807    HLT35021      Title1b      Superseded        1
3 HLT31812    HLT35021      Title1c      Superseded        1
4 HLT35015    HLT35021      Title1d      Superseded        1
5 HLT35021    HLT35021      Title1e      Current           1
6 ABC12345    ABC67890      Title2a      Superseded        2
7 ABC67890    ABC67890      Title2b      Current           2
```

Comment: upvoted! :) may I edit your answer slightly

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thanks. Yes, you can edit it as you want.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, thanks so much for the help. Also works brilliantly. I'm definitely going to have to look into igraph more!

Comment: instead of having one extra statement of mutate, you may create a new variable directly in group_by statement

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you so much. I learn new things from you regarding `dplyr` :) I had very limited knowledge on `dplyr`.

Comment: @ClintonThorncraft You are welcome. I guess you can break down the code by lines to see how it works in a more clear manner.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use `course_title` column you may also do something like this.

- Used `igraph` to create an individual cluster for each `parent-child`.
- thereafter used that cluster-id `values` in our case, for group_by for actual data.
- to perform network analysis of `parent-child` I also had to remove `None` from parent and replaced it with child itself whenever a `None` is found.

Hope the other syntax is pretty clear.  Else ask for an explnation

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'Course_Code    Course_Title    Course_Status   Parent_Course
HLT31802    Title1a Superseded  HLT31807
HLT31807    Title1b Superseded  HLT31812
HLT31812    Title1c Superseded  HLT35015
HLT35015    Title1d Superseded  HLT35021
HLT35021    Title1e Current None
ABC12345    Title2a Superseded  ABC67890
ABC67890    Title2b Current None')

library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

df %>%
  mutate(Parent_Course = ifelse(Parent_Course == 'None', Course_Code, Parent_Course)) %>%
  select(1,4) %>%
  graph.data.frame() %>%
  components() %>%
  pluck(membership) %>%
  stack() %>%
  right_join(df, by = c('ind' = 'Course_Code')) %>%
  group_by(values) %>%
  mutate(Parent_Course = ind[Course_Status == 'Current'], .keep = 'used') %>%
  rename(Course_Code = ind)

#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   values [2]
#>   values Course_Code Course_Status Parent_Course
#>    <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>        
#> 1      1 HLT31802    Superseded    HLT35021     
#> 2      1 HLT31807    Superseded    HLT35021     
#> 3      1 HLT31812    Superseded    HLT35021     
#> 4      1 HLT35015    Superseded    HLT35021     
#> 5      1 HLT35021    Current       HLT35021     
#> 6      2 ABC12345    Superseded    ABC67890     
#> 7      2 ABC67890    Current       ABC67890
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Unreal. Thanks so much for your help @AnilGoyal. Works on the larger set of data I had. Ill go through it now, and come back to you if I get stuck :)

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, I tagged it with `igraph` so that you may notice it and simplify it perhaps.  :)  Thanks for upvote.  My little knowledge in this library is due to you only

Comment: Thank you as well. The `igraph` tag always catches my eyes :P.

Answer (score 1):

By using the packages `stringr` and `dplyr`:

```
df <- data %>% 
  filter(Course_Status == "Current") %>% 
  mutate(Ety = str_sub(Course_Code, 1, 3)) %>% 
  select(-Course_Status) %>% 
  rename(Current_Course = Course_Code)


df2 <- data %>% 
  select(Course_Code) %>% 
  mutate(Ety = str_sub(Course_Code, 1, 3))


res <- left_join(df2, df, by = "Ety")
res <- res %>% 
  select(-Ety)

res
```

Comment: Thanks MonJeanJean. Works on the sample data, but how would I go about it where there are multiple current courses with the same first three letters?

Comment: Depends on what you expect the other Course_Code the value to take. Saying for HLT you have 2 Current courses, how do you choose which one will give the value to the variable **Current_couse**?

Comment: Yeah, I thought the sample data might be an issue :) Its a listing of entries that already contain their 'parent' course, but it only goes one level up. Thank you so much for helping out though, and pointing me towards stringr :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Have a nice day @ClintonThorncraft